# Run a block if a condition pass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6, ruby-2.6

I want to run this block only a condition is satisfied

```
<% if condition %>
 <% progressive_render do %>
   SLOW CODE HERE
 <% end %>
<% end %>
```

IF **condition = true**

SLOW CODE should be runnned wrapped by "progressive_render"

IF **condition = true**

SLOW CODE shoud be runned not wrapped by progressive_render. So runned anyway.

Comment: `if condition = true` twice?

Comment: Just to be extra careful

Comment: "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)" is your friend. Your question doesn't make sense. As @SebastianPalma pointed out you are asking about two identical conditions expecting different results. Also, please note that grammar/spelling are very important on SO as the site is like an online encyclopedia, not a message board.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the `if-else` condition with a guard clause (plus `unless` condition):

```
<% SLOW CODE HERE unless condition %>
<% progressive_render { SLOW CODE HERE } %>
```